# I need Multiple choice questions with cross tabulations including Totals in R Programming. Below is what I am looking for

Tags: r

I am creating frequency tables by using R with cross tabulations. Somehow, I am unable to create the Multiple choice questions with cross tabulations. Can someone please guide me how exactly we need to write the code.

Here is my dataset:

[image]

Expected Results:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, do not add images of tables, rather the output of `dput(your_data)`, so that we can help you!

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to cross-tabulation in R.
A solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
  q1 = sample(x = c("yes", "no"), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  q2_1 = sample(x = 0:1, size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  q2_2 = sample(x = 0:1, size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  q2_3 = sample(x = 0:1, size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  q2_4 = sample(x = 0:1, size = 10, replace = TRUE)
)

head(data)

   q1 q2_1 q2_2 q2_3 q2_4
1 yes    0    0    0    0
2 yes    0    0    1    1
3  no    1    1    0    1
4  no    0    0    0    0
5  no    1    0    1    0
6  no    1    1    0    0

#long format data

longdata <- gather(data,key = "q2","value"  ,-q1)

ftable(longdata)

         value 0 1
q1  q2            
no  q2_1       4 3
    q2_2       3 4
    q2_3       5 2
    q2_4       5 2
yes q2_1       2 1
    q2_2       2 1
    q2_3       1 2
    q2_4       1 2
```